# How to export validation rules from salesforce into excel sheet?

Tags: validation-rule

Is there any way to export all the validation rules in the organisation and export it to excel sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly or easily, but it is doable. First, you need to export the metadata which you can do with the Force.com IDE or the Force.com Ant migration tool.  You can get either from the tools part of setup.

Once you get the object files, you will see metadata like this:

```
<validationRules>
    <fullName>Opt_Out_Required_Reason</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <description>Require a reason when op outs are checked</description>
    <errorConditionFormula>AND(OR(DoNotCall = true, HasOptedOutOfEmail = true), ISBLANK( TEXT(Opt_Out_Reason__c )))</errorConditionFormula>
    <errorDisplayField>Opt_Out_Reason__c</errorDisplayField>
    <errorMessage>You must select an opt-out reason if you indicate that this Lead is opting out of email or phone calls.</errorMessage>
</validationRules>
```

From there, you can format that into an excel table.